# Adding multiple vectors in R

Tags: r, vector

I have a problem where I have to add thirty-three integer vectors of equal length from a dataset in R. I know the simple solution would be

```
Vector1 + Vector2 + Vector3 +VectorN
```

But I am sure there is a way to code this. Also some vectors have NA in place of integers so I need a way to skip those. I know this may be very basic but I am new to this.

Comment: I recommend using the `r` tag rather than `rstats`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is another way, dropping NAs when sum the vectors:

```
df <- data.frame(vector1, vector2, vector3, vector4)
rowSums(df, na.rm=T)
```

Comment: This can also do the job:
`apply(df, 1, sum, na.rm=TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's not as easy as it may seem. I reckon you want to get rid of NA's and replace them with 0 (zeros). Yet another solution is:

```
# create dummy variables
set.seed(1234)
x <- round(rnorm(10, 15, 3.2))
y <- round(runif(10, 12, 27))
z <- round(rpois(n = 10, lambda = 5))
# create some NA's
x[c(2,3)] <- NA
y[c(1,3,7)] <- NA
z[c(3,6,10)] <- NA
```

And now, if you do:

```
x + y + z  # the result is:
[1] NA NA NA 20 31 41 NA 39 37 25
```

So run:

```
x[is.na(x)] <- 0
y[is.na(y)] <- 0
z[is.na(z)] <- 0
```

hence:

```
x + y + z  # yields:
[1] 16 21  0 25 34 41 16 42 48 25
```

But, frankly, I recommend that you stick with **@xiechao**'s solution!
It's quite easy and straightforward!

Answer (score 1):

here is where mapply comes to its field:

```
mapply(sum,Vector1,Vector2,Vector3,VectorN,na.rm = TRUE)
```

simple intelligent and clear

Answer (score 0):

```
do.call("+", list(vector1, vector2, vector3, vector4))
```

Comment: this only works if the list has two elements; otherwise it complains: "operator needs one or two arguments"

Comment: this can't handle the NA case

Answer (score 0):

```
add = function(...) {
  vectors = list(...)
  res=vectors[[1]]
  for(i in vectors[-1]) res = res + i
  return(res)
}

add(1:3,4:5,1:3)
```